# Setting background Image for DIV

Tags: html, css

I have a `div`, which I need to set a background image for in the `CSS` file:

**Template:**

```
<div class="myBG">  Some Text Here </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.myBG{
    background-image: url('ImageURL');
    color: #00FA9A;
    font-family:Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

To set `ImageURL` I tried web links as well as links to images on my disk, but it does not work and I do not get any background to my div. Can you find out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: How is that related to Angular?

Comment: It is in one of my components that I am writing.
Anyhow, the tags modified (Angular removed):

Comment: i will give u an example as a hint `background: white url("img_tree.gif") no-repeat center center;` -> `white` can be any color for fallback, `center center` can be also dimensions in `px` - but the question is quite simple to be solved and not angular specific - try to inspect also the `myBG` computed dimensions - maybe the height is 0 or maybe the background images is not centered. Try also `background-size: cover;` in the end of the css

Comment: I go through your example, thanks.
I know it is simple, but I have not been able to sort it out!

Comment: i put my comment as an answer cause it was too long :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to position the background for example: `background: blue url("ImageURL.png") no-repeat center center;` , specify the size of the background with `background-size: cover;` or with pixels instead of `cover`, make sure that the computed `width` and `height` values of the `div` are not `0` and that there is no `404` error while trying to fetch the image from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.
The main problem was using improper image links, which had made me confused!